# JWT Module can't compile

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core

After adding a few lines of code I described below appears

I have a problem, when I try to compile Angular, I have this error:

```
ERROR in node_modules/@auth0/angular-jwt/index.d.ts:29:48 - error NG6005: JwtModule.forRoot returns a ModuleWithProviders type without a generic type argument. Please add a generic type argument to the ModuleWithProviders type. If this occurrence is in library code you don't control, please contact the library authors.

29     static forRoot(options: JwtModuleOptions): ModuleWithProviders;
                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/app.component.html:9:1 - error NG8001: 'app-nav' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-nav' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-nav' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

9 <app-nav></app-nav>
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:8:16
    8   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.
src/app/app.component.html:10:1 - error NG8001: 'router-outlet' is not a known element:
1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

10 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:8:16
    8   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.
src/app/nav/nav.component.html:3:33 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.

3         <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['/home']">Dating App</a>
                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/nav/nav.component.ts:8:16
    8   templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component NavComponent.
src/app/register/register.component.html:6:74 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

6         <input type="text" class="form-control" required name="username" [(ngModel)]="model.username" placeholder="Username">
                                                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/register/register.component.ts:8:16
    8   templateUrl: './register.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component RegisterComponent.
src/app/register/register.component.html:11:78 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

11         <input type="password" class="form-control" required name="password" [(ngModel)]="model.password" placeholder="Password">
                                                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/register/register.component.ts:8:16
    8   templateUrl: './register.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component RegisterComponent.
src/app/register/register.component.html:1:22 - error NG8003: No directive found with exportAs 'ngForm'.

1 <form #registerForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="register()">
                       ~~~~~~

  src/app/register/register.component.ts:8:16
    8   templateUrl: './register.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component RegisterComponent.
```

this i my index.d.ts

```
import { ModuleWithProviders, Provider } from '@angular/core';


export * from './src/jwt.interceptor';
export * from './src/jwthelper.service';
export * from './src/jwtoptions.token';
export interface JwtModuleOptions {
    jwtOptionsProvider?: Provider;
    config?: {
        tokenGetter?: () => string | null | Promise<string | null>;
        headerName?: string;
        authScheme?: string;
        whitelistedDomains?: Array<string | RegExp>;
        blacklistedRoutes?: Array<string | RegExp>;
        throwNoTokenError?: boolean;
        skipWhenExpired?: boolean;
    };
}

declare module "@angular/core" {
    interface ModuleWithProviders<T = any> {
        ngModule: Type<T>;
        providers?: Provider[];
    }
}

export declare class JwtModule {
    constructor(parentModule: JwtModule);
    static forRoot(options: JwtModuleOptions): ModuleWithProviders;
    
}

//# sourceMappingURL=index.d.ts.map
```

this is my app.module.ts:

```
import { MemberCardComponent } from './members/member-card/member-card.component';
import { appRoutes } from './routes';
import { ErrorInterceptorProvider } from './_services/error.interceptor';
import { AuthService } from './_services/auth.service';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {FormsModule, } from '@angular/forms';
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { JwtModule } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';



import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { MemberListComponent } from './members/member-list/member-list.component';
import { ListsComponent } from './lists/lists.component';
import { MessagesComponent } from './messages/messages.component';




// tslint:disable-next-line:typedef
export function tokenGetter(){
   return localStorage.getItem('token');
}


@NgModule({
   declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      NavComponent,
      RegisterComponent,
      HomeComponent,
      MemberListComponent,
      ListsComponent,
      MessagesComponent,
      MemberCardComponent
   ],
   imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      HttpClientModule,
      FormsModule,
      BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
      RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
      JwtModule.forRoot({
         config: {
         // tslint:disable-next-line:object-literal-shorthand
         tokenGetter: tokenGetter,
         whitelistedDomains: ['localhost:5000'],
         blacklistedRoutes: ['localhost:5000/api/auth']
         }
      }),
   ],
   providers: [
      AuthService,
      ErrorInterceptorProvider
   ],
   bootstrap: [
      AppComponent
   ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Tt only adds that to app.module.ts:

```
// tslint:disable-next-line:typedef
    export function tokenGetter(){
       return localStorage.getItem('token');
    }
```

and

```
JwtModule.forRoot({
             config: {
             // tslint:disable-next-line:object-literal-shorthand
             tokenGetter: tokenGetter,
             whitelistedDomains: ['localhost:5000'],
             blacklistedRoutes: ['localhost:5000/api/auth']
             }
          }),
```

As I add this JWT module and try to add it to the project file I can't compile it if the problem is with the Angular version or it's something else.
I can't compile my program, How can I solve this problem.;/

Comment: What is your angular version and your auth0 version?

Comment: angular: 10.0.8, auth0: 2.1.2

Comment: You might want to try an @latest on auth0

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: npm i @auth0@latest I guess..? Unless you used a deeper package. Check your package.json, take the auto0 name from there an add the @latest (no space)

Comment: I only have one place to change @ auth0 to @latest even if I change it is the same.

Comment: @ŁukaszKraśniak did you solve this exception?